# How to implement a corner page curl UI?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an app with two full-screen views, one on top of the other. I would like to show the corner of the top view curled slightly away, and allow the user to curl it away more until the view underneath is completely showing.

The user should be able to interact with whatever part of the view underneath is exposed, and with whatever part of the view above is exposed.

I'd especially like this to look and feel like the page turn curling in iBooks. I've done a lot of searching about the iBooks page curl, but not much turns up. There's a great [OpenGL implementation](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html), but I don't know how to get from there to here. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for the awesome blog post link.

Comment: thats a GREAT blog tutorial..what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well the OpenGL implementaton uses an EAGLView, but in my app I have two UIViews that I want to do this with. I'm not sure how to get this page curl effect using the UIViews.

Comment: Thanks for the great blog post! OpenGL is probably the only way to go here, I can't imagine achieving that transform without resorting to OpenGL at some level, including Apple's own private API's.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler to implement, and therefore simpler visually approach is available here: http://github.com/brow/leaves

You may have a bit more success starting small.

Comment: Well, that's an option... but its not very beautiful. And doing it that way doesn't seem to get me any closer to doing it the right way. I'll keep in mind as a fallback.